# Ping from Windows 7 computer to own Ubuntu virtual machine

Tags: ubuntu, virtual-machine, ping

I can't do Ping to my own virtual machine.
The system of my computer is Windows 7, and virtual machine( with Oracle Virtual Box) is ubuntu.

I don't understand the reason.
I haven't proxy

Thank you very much

Answer (score 0):

This depends on the virtual networking setup for your virtual machine.

You mention virtual box, which supports many different networking modes, but the default is NAT, which means the virtual machine can make outgoing network connections, but incoming packets are only forwarded for those connections, so there's no way to ping the VM.

You can allow incoming TCP connections by forwarding certain ports to the VM (much as you would do with a NAT firewall router), but that still doesn't allow for pings.

Alternately, you can use a different [virtualbox networking](https://www.virtualbox.org/manual/ch06.html) mode -- bridged, internal, or host-only networking, each of which involves setting up a virtual network with virtual network adaptors on the host.  Once these are set up, you can ping the VM from the host, and you can even set up routing on the host, so the VM can be pinged from other hosts.

Answer (score 0):

1. Make sure than Host OS and Guest OS inside the same sub-net
2. Make sure than software Firewall on Guest OS is disabled, or, rules for PING enabled
3. In VirtualBox try to change network settings to "Bridged Adapter"

[image]